# ThreeJS Bloom Example copied line by line, but does not produce the same effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Here is a comparison between the online example and my output for a bloom filter.

**Online**

[image: Online Example]

**Mine**

[image]

Mine does not produce the desired glowing effect shown in the first image, although the example is copied exactly. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

**Online Example Code**

https://codesandbox.io/s/7mfqw?file=/src/index.js

**My Code**

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import React, { useRef, useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import { Canvas, extend, useThree, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { EffectComposer } from "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer";
import { RenderPass } from "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass";
import { UnrealBloomPass } from "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass";
import styles from "./MyCanvas.module.scss";

extend({ EffectComposer, RenderPass, UnrealBloomPass });

function Sphere({ geometry, x, y, z, s }) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useFrame((state) => {
    ref.current.position.x =
      x + Math.sin((state.clock.getElapsedTime() * s) / 2);
    ref.current.position.y =
      y + Math.sin((state.clock.getElapsedTime() * s) / 2);
    ref.current.position.z =
      z + Math.sin((state.clock.getElapsedTime() * s) / 2);
  });
  return (
    <mesh ref={ref} position={[x, y, z]} scale={[s, s, s]} geometry={geometry}>
      <meshStandardMaterial color="hotpink" roughness={1} />
    </mesh>
  );
}

function RandomSpheres() {
  const [geometry] = useState(() => new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32), []);
  const data = useMemo(() => {
    return new Array(15).fill().map((_, i) => ({
      x: Math.random() * 100 - 50,
      y: Math.random() * 100 - 50,
      z: Math.random() * 100 - 50,
      s: Math.random() + 10,
    }));
  }, []);
  return data.map((props, i) => (
    <Sphere key={i} {...props} geometry={geometry} />
  ));
}

function Bloom({ children }) {
  const { gl, camera, size } = useThree();
  const [scene, setScene] = useState();
  const composer = useRef();
  useEffect(
    () => void scene && composer.current.setSize(size.width, size.height),
    [size]
  );
  useFrame(() => scene && composer.current.render(), 1);
  return (
    <>
      <scene ref={setScene}>{children}</scene>
      <effectComposer ref={composer} args={[gl]}>
        <renderPass attachArray="passes" scene={scene} camera={camera} />
        <unrealBloomPass attachArray="passes" args={[undefined, 1.5, 1, 0]} />
      </effectComposer>
    </>
  );
}

function Main({ children }) {
  const scene = useRef();
  const { gl, camera } = useThree();
  useFrame(() => {
    gl.autoClear = false;
    gl.clearDepth();
    gl.render(scene.current, camera);
  }, 2);
  return <scene ref={scene}>{children}</scene>;
}

function MyCanvas(props) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.Canvas}>
      <Canvas linear camera={{ position: [0, 0, 120] }}>
        <Main>
          <pointLight />
          <ambientLight />
          <RandomSpheres />
        </Main>
        <Bloom>
          <ambientLight />
          <RandomSpheres />
        </Bloom>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyCanvas;
```

Comment: Did you copy the CSS as well?

Comment: Good idea. It changed the background color but the lighting still is the same, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

These libraries worked for me. I was importing older libraries from example folders and I can't say for certain, i'd say that would be the issue.

```
import { Effects } from '@react-three/drei'
import { UnrealBloomPass } from 'three-stdlib'
```

Working example shared on the three.js forums.
https://codesandbox.io/s/bloom-hdr-workflow-gnn4yt